# ajax function for returning values from 2 server-side scripts to 2 DOM targets

Tags: javascript, ajax

What I'm trying to do 
The tizag example has the DOM being changed inside of the onreadystatechange function, like this:

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
}
```

But I want to change values in multiple DOM targets, so my idea was to try to return a value instead. I adapated the code, but obviously it doesn't work.

Here is the complete code as I adapted it. You can see where I try to access 2 different scripts at the bottom. Is this at all possible?:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            return ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/time.php", true);
    var time = ajaxRequest.send(null);  // trying to get value from 1st script
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/date.php", true);
    var date = ajaxRequest.send(null); // trying to get values from 2nd script

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time; // send 1st variable to DOM
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date; // send 2nd variable to DOM
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 3rd parameter in the call to `ajax.open` indicates that the request is executed asynchronously, which means that the return value from the `ajax.send` call won't be the results of the script from the server.

You should set your local variables in the body of the anonymous function attached to `onreadystatechange`.  You can probably inspect the ajax object to determine which server script returned.

It may be easier to create 2 different ajax objects, 1 for the request to get the date, and another for the request to get the time.

Also I would suggest looking into jquery, which does a lot of the plumbing for you and presents a much simpler way to execute ajax requests.